# How to connect stripe account by a connect button in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, strip

I'm trying to implement below doc , where in my website there will be a stripe connect button after click on button if user login then user will connect and I will save user stripe session id.

https://stripe.com/docs/building-extensions

But this doc is deprecated.

In stripe docs not getting any clue how I will do the same thing. I have tried by

```
$stripeAccountLink = $this->StripeClient->accountLinks->create([
            'account' => 'acct_1MQqv1SHt2ASWOGp',
            'refresh_url' => url("/profile-edit"),
            'return_url' => url("/profile-edit"),
            'type' => 'account_onboarding',
]);
```

So here after redirect user always user need to create a new account. Why it's not just connect and redirect me if user already log in and am I in right way ?

docs : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts

Comment: Can you clarify what your expectation is here? When creating an Account Link like you have, if your user has an existing Stripe account they can authenticate using those credentials at the onboarding URL you redirect them to. They'll then need to provide the onboarding information required.

Comment: I'm actually in confusing state, would you please tell me I'm in right path to connect user account with my site ? If user redirect in return_url then I have to make status confirm connect user ?

Comment: You'd setup and configure a [Connect webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks) on your platform account to subscribe to `account.updated` events, which will fire during and after your users complete the onboarding flow. This process is detailed [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#return-user).